# Xamarin SQLite: What is different SQLiteAsyncConnection and SQLiteConnection

Tags: sqlite, asynchronous, xamarin, portable-class-library

There are two type of constructors I can call to initialise the Sqlite connection. I know SQLiteAsyncConnection is to create an async method when execute the sql statement whereas SQLiteConnection is for normal method.

If I have a method like below:

```
public object InsertVeggie(string name) 
{
   lock (locker) {
      var sql = "Some query ?";
      var result = database.Query<Model>(sql, name);
      return result;
   }        
}
```

If I have an async method:

```
public async Task<Model> GetModel (string name) 
{
    var data = InsertVeggie(name);
    await ProcessVeggie(data);
    return data;
}
```

Calling method :

```
Task.Run (async () => 
{ 
   var result1 = await GetModel("124");
});

Task.Run (async () => 
{ 
   var result2 = await GetModel("335");
});
```

If I use SQLiteConnection instead of SQLiteAsyncConnection, will there be an issue or have to change the InsertVeggie to Async method as well.

Comment: do you mean, 'If I use SQLiteAsyncConnection instead of SQLiteConnection'?

Comment: Partly Yes... Coz my code for accessing database isn't mark Async but in other methods which call that method may be async task.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, `SQLiteAsyncConnection` exposes asynchronous methods so you would typically consume them from your own `async` methods.

Your `InsertVeggie` method would change to:

```
public async Task<object> InsertVeggie(string name) 
{
  var sql = "Some query ?";
  var result = await database.QueryAsync<Model>(sql, name);
  return result;     
}
```

(note you no longer need the lock), and you would consume it as:

```
var data = await InsertVeggie(name);
```